# fcitx consume 93.4% cpu

Tags: htop

I check processes with htop and find

[image]

the input method manager/fcitx consumes 93.4% cpu,

What's might be the problem?
Is it a single cpu or all the cpu?

Comment: Same happening here with Debian 9.

Comment: Similar thing on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Same with Debian 10 now.